# How to compare dates and times in Yii 2 ActiveRecord?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, yii2, sql-timestamp

Im totally confused, how can i compare dates and times in Yii ActiveRecord?

I have this method in my model:

```
public static someMethod(){
    self::updateAll(['status' => SomeModel::STATUS_ACTIVE], [
        'status' => SomeModel::STATUS_ONLINE, 
        'last_seen_timestamp_no_timezone + 15 minutes < now()' 
    ]);
}
```

How can I add condition: `last_seen_timestamp_no_timezone + 15 minutes < now()` to my updateAll() call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with php:

```
public static someMethod(){
   self::updateAll(['status' => SomeModel::STATUS_ACTIVE], [
       'AND',
       ['status' => SomeModel::STATUS_ONLINE], 
       ['<', 'last_seen_timestamp_no_timezone', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-15 minutes'))]
   ]);
}
```